Existence of $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$-regular unit tangent field on smooth surface
Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded, smooth, simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$. My goal is to show that there is a $p(x) \in H^1(\Omega,\mathbb{S}^2)$ such that $p(x)$ lies on the tangent plane of $x \in \partial \Omega$ in the sense of trace.
Let's reduce the problem. First, as the boundary of the domain is smooth, we can suppose that $\partial\Omega=\mathbb{S}^2$. Second, for any $p^0 \in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2;\mathbb{S}^2)$, there is a $p(x) \in H^{1}(\Omega;\mathbb{S}^2)$ such that $p=p^0$ on $\partial\Omega$ in the sense of trace, by Theorem 6.2 of [1]. Thus, I am going to find a $p^0 \in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2;\mathbb{S}^2)$.
I am going to compute the $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)$ norm of the example $p^0(x)=\left(\dfrac{-x_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},\dfrac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}},0\right)$. It is enough to compute the seminorm:
$$[p^0]_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}=\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\dfrac{|p^0(x)-p^0(y)|^2}{|x-y|^3}dS^2_xdS^2_y.$$
The first question is that shall we use the metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$ to compute the term $|p^0(x)-p^0(y)|^2$ and also $|x-y|^3$? If yes, then we can use the spherical coordinate:
$$[p^0]_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}=\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^\pi_0\int^\pi_0\frac{ \left(\varphi-\varphi^*\right)^2\sin \theta \sin\theta^* }{|\cos^{-1}\left(\cos(\theta^*)\cos(\theta)
+\sin(\theta^*)\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi-\varphi^*)\right)|^{3}}d\theta d\theta^* d\varphi d\varphi^*.$$
It seems to me that the integral is complicated. The second question is that is there any good idea to compute this? I think it should be finite, the reason is as follows: Consider the map $p^1(x):=x/|x|$ from $B_1$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$. It is well-known that $\|p^1\|_{H^1(B_1)}<\infty$ which yields that $\|p^1\|_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}<\infty$ by the trace theorem. We compute that
$$[p^1]_{H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^2)}=\int^{2\pi}_0\int^{2\pi}_0\int^\pi_0\int^\pi_0\frac{ \sin \theta \sin\theta^* }{|\cos^{-1}\left(\cos(\theta^*)\cos(\theta)
+\sin(\theta^*)\sin(\theta)\cos(\varphi-\varphi^*)\right)|}d\theta d\theta^* d\varphi d\varphi^*<\infty.$$
I think the integral $[p^1]_{H^{1/2}}$ and $[p^0]_{H^{1/2}}$ are very similar.
Or is there another method to find the existence of such a vector field?
[1] Hardt, R., & Lin, F. H. (1987). Mappings minimizing the Lp norm of the gradient. Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics, 40(5), 555-588.

I would suggest to compute the $H^{1/2}$-norm of a vector field in the plane with a similar singularity (and with compact support). Have you tried that?

Do you mean to use the stereographic projection to transform the sphere to the plane?

Yes, except that I would multiply the resulting vector field with a cut-off function supported in a ball around 0 to avoid artefacts from the measure distortion outside of a compact set.
